# Tensorflow - retrieve variable (shape must be fully defined)

Tags: tensorflow

I'm training a convnet with Tensorflow but I'm having troubles with it, so I'm trying to figure out what's happening.
I've defined some variable in the following way:

```
with tf.variable_scope('myscope') as scope:
    var = some_value
```

But when I try to retrieve it:

```
var = tf.get_variable('myscope/var')
```

I get the following:

```
ValueError: Shape of a new variable (myscope/var) must be fully defined, but instead was <unknown>.
```

I think there might be something wrong with my tensors, because when I print the output shape I get `(?, 10)` while I should have the batch size instead of the `?`. [Here's my code](https://github.com/alegaballo/AlexNet_CNN/blob/master/AlexNet.ipynb) for completeness.

Comment: Are you sure, you really want to use `tf.get_variable` which creates a new variable? I guess you are interested in `tf.contrib.framework.get_variables_by_name` or `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name`

Comment: @Patwie not really :) I'm new to tensorflow and I'm experimenting. I've tried the first method but it doesn't retrieve the variable, the second one seems more complicated and probably more than I need. What I've noticed in the meanwhile is that the dimension of the tensor is unknown from the beginning, even after I set the batch size, it still remains `?`

Comment: If you write a small example which can directly reproduce the error your chances are much higher to get a meaningful and helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced the same problem. The shape is undefined if it has a ?, which means it can take any value. It works well if you manually define your shape (like [10, 10] instead of [?,10]) while declaring the tensor variable.

Comment: The problem is that the tensor dimension depends on the batch size, which I don't know when I define the variable

Comment: I went through your code. Great work commenting and explaining the process. Also, since you are using a batch size and iterator to get the training data in batches, the size would not be always 128.

Consider a dataset of size 312 and your batch size is 128. The first two batches have 128 each. But the last batch has 56. Hence, the tensorflow works in such a way that it does not have a limit on the batch size.

<BatchDataset shapes: ((?, 32, 32, 3), (?, 10)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>